# Flutter ListView.builder sizedbox problem

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

When I try to scroll down to see whole text, I can't scroll down. I think the problem is sizedbox's height.

[image]

I use sizedbox, because If I do not use above listview builder, then It does not show anything.

codes:

```
Column(
children: [
           SizedBox(
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
           child: ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
           itemCount:
           snapshotPosts.data?.data()!["random"]?.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {..})...
```

Comment: You can used `Expanded` instead of `SizedBox` since it's child of a `Column`.

Comment: @esentis I tried, but, since it has not height, it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find anything on the network, but i solved like this:
I removed the Sizedbox, and I put card instead of sizedbox.
It is not enough of course. I also removed the second futureBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

After the first SizedBox that you have used, you can add other SizedBox with no child, for example:

```
SizedBox(
 height: 50,
),
```

Or for being responsive for any screen, you can use this:

```
SizedBox(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
),
```

By this way you add empty space to see above Widgets.